# Restrict queries to specific Amazon Athena database using jdbc url

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

Is it possible to restrict queries to a certain Amazon Athena database, so that queries are run only against that database?

I imagine something like

```
jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/databasename
```

, so that queries like

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable
```

are possible. Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM databasename.exampletable
```

Grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible using following JDBC url:

```
jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/AwsDataCatalog/databasename
```

If you connect using this url, you don't need to add the database name every time you access a table.

Comment: I was able to use this solution to run MSCK REPAIR TABLE, which doesn't seem to allow qualifying the table name with the database name.

Comment: I tried this URL but it did not work for me (the queried database remained the default). Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a Schema Property in the jdbc url as follows ;

```
jdbc:awsathena://athena.[Region].amazonaws.com:443;User=[AccessKey];Password=[SecretKey];S3OutputLocation=[Output];Schema=[databasename];
```

then you can perform queries without the database name as follows;

```sql
SELECT * FROM exampletable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a database with Athena at the time of connection via JDBC. This is outlined in the Athena docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html).

Here is the snippet that describes database namespaces in Athena statements.

> The JDBC uses the default database but you can also create databases and use them. In this case, you should use the database identifier as a namespace prefix to your table name when writing your queries, to distinguish between tables in the default and custom databases.